# Android Support v7 Toolbar setTitleTextAppearance not working

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I am trying to change the font of the toolbar's title.
Here is my toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#666666"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyText"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>
```

And in my styles.xml

```
<style name="MyText">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/myFont.ttf</item>
</style>
```

If I do not set `app:titleTextAppearance`, the toolbar uses the system font. When I set it, the font gets smaller, but it is still in the system font. Am I doing something wrong?

Any suggestion, comments or answers much appreciated.

#### Edit:

I tried moving the style to `styles-text.xml` but no luck

#### Edit2:

For now, I am using a SpannableString and [TypefaceSpan](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2013/03/styling-the-android-action-bar-with-a-custom-font/) to make this work. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: It doesn't change the font

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ActionBarTitleStyle"/>
```

Then have this in your styles.xml

```
<style name="ActionBarTitle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">

    <!-- The action bar title font -->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>

    <!-- Customizes the color of the action bar title-->
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>

    <!-- Customizes the size of the action bar title-->
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the font:family is only applied if I use "*android:titleTextAppearance*" instead of "*app:titleTextAppearance*" but this only works for api 21 or higher