# `titleTextAppearance` is not working

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

Why `titleTextAppearance` is not working with this action bar on a navigation drawer activity, I want to change the Title size and to be the same on landscape/portrait

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <include layout="@layout/content_start" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_start"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_start_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_start.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleStyle"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

<include layout="@layout/content_start" />
```

and this is content_start.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivityRelated.StartActivity"

    android:id="@+id/RR">

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the styles are:

```
  <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>


    <style name="ToolbarTitleStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try to change `parent=Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title`.

Comment: Unfortunately, This didn't work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just Edit the following to the toolbar

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

app_bar_start.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitleStyle"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ToolBarStyle" />

<include layout="@layout/content_start" />
```

Source: [Android Support v7 Toolbar setTitleTextAppearance not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27530215/android-support-v7-toolbar-settitletextappearance-not-working)